# Finding prime numbers in an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to iterate through an array and determine if each number is prime or not.

Here is my code:

**constants.h**

```
#pragma once
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H

namespace constants {

    constexpr int randomOne[10] = { 1,3,5,7,9,12,13,15,18,23 };

}

#endif // !CONSTANTS_H
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "constants.h"

int main() {
//Check a number in an array to see if it is prime or not
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i) {
        //std::cout << constants::randomOne[i] << '\n'; 
        //Uncomment the line above and the console prints each number in the array

//To check how many times the number in the array has been divided between 1 and itself we take count and increment it each time it is divided.
//If the count is greater than two (2) we know the number is not prime.
        for (int j = 1; j <= constants::randomOne[i]; ++j) 
        {
            if(constants::randomOne[i] % j == 0)
                ++count;
        }
        //The above code should divide the number in the array by one and increment up by one all the way up to the number.
        //If it returns a value higher than two than the number is not prime. 
        //Example: Say the number in the array is 4 so - 4 % 1 = 0, 4 % 2 = 0, 4 % 3 != 0, 4 % 4 = 0 would increment to three (3) so four is not prime.
        if (count == 2)
        {
            std::cout << constants::randomOne[i] << " is not prime, rather it is a composite number.\n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << constants::randomOne[i] << " is prime!!!\n";
        }
    } 
}
```

When I run the code it returns:

```
3 is not prime, rather it is a composite number.
5 is prime!!!
7 is prime!!!
9 is prime!!!
12 is prime!!!
13 is prime!!!
15 is prime!!!
18 is prime!!!
23 is prime!!!
1052166324 is prime!!!
```

I have totally messed this up, where did I go wrong? How come I am not getting the correct prime or not prime number response?

**Edit** Thank you all for bearing with my "out of guidelines" post long enough to give me some pointers. The suggestions were all very helpful, especially using my debugger (learncpp.com has some great lessons on how to use it btw). The debugger helped me visualize where my code logic was falling apart. Also removing some of the code logic from main was another good suggestion. My solution can be found [here](https://blog.mountaintopcoding.com/cpp)

Also (and not really relevant to my overall question, but now I am curious) how the heck did I get `1,052,166,324`? Int holds 2,147,483,647 if it is unsigned, if it is signed up to ~1,073,741,823 positive which is ~21,575,499 short of what my console spit out. Also, the array is 10 digits long, so why did it skip 1 at the front of the array and add the HUGE number to the end? Is this a compiler-specific issue? Or did it just throw in random memory from the 10 address?

Comment: Arrays in C++ start at index 0, not 1.  You're going out of bounds with `randomOne[10]`.

Comment: The shown code attempts to access `randomOne[1]` through `randomOne[10]`. The problem with this is that there is no such thing as `randomOne[10]`. As such, the shown code is undefined behavior. Only `randomOne[0]` through `randomOne[9]`, actually exist, that's how 0-based array indexing works in C++.

Comment: As for your other bug, this is a great chance to learn how to use your debugger.  Your program is small enough that it's a fantastic example to learn from.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is simply asking why a bug-ridden program isn't working. It can be of little help to future readers except as an object lesson.

Comment: Create a function called `bool isPrime(int value)` that returns `true` or `false` depending on whether `value` is prime.  Then test it with various values.  Right now, you have everything all munged in the `main` function, making the issue more difficult to debug.  With a function, you can test it with various values first.  Once the function works, then it doesn't matter where the data comes from -- just call the function with the data.

Comment: *"if it is signed up to ~1,073,741,823 positive which is ~21,575,499 short of what my console spit out."* -- you mean "more than", not "short of", don't you? In the ten-millions place, the console listed 5, which is less than 7.

Comment: You might have an easier time debugging if you delegate tasks to helper functions. In this case, I would expect to see a function whose task is to determine whether or not its parameter is prime -- a focused, single task. Make sure that function works as intended. Question that function when it says that `3` is not prime. Once you have that function working, look into your looping error. Divide and conquer, one bug at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the out-of-bounds error mentioned in the comments, you get the logic backwards -- saying that if `count==2` then the number is *not* prime -- and you neglect to reset `count`.

In short, your code is full of bugs which you could have spotted if you had started with something small and simple that worked perfectly, then build up in small increments, testing at every step. If you write this much code without testing it, you will invariably construct a nest of bugs. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [github project from Dave Plummer](https://github.com/PlummersSoftwareLLC/Primes) (retired MSFT C/C++). It's a really cool comparison of different languages using a prime sieve so I believe it will answer your question and demonstrate an optimized program. Plus you can look at how C++ stacks up against other common languages. (Spoiler alert, C++ almost always wins)

Comment: The question was where did this code go wrong, not how to check for primes. Are you saying that the linked project will explain why the question's code gives incorrect results?

Comment: Also, answers should be self-contained. Useful links are good, but the core of the answer should be in the answer itself. See [answer].